# Fix letter after and before period, even inside differents divs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a huge json file, that is like a tree decision, each node of the json has a sentence.
And there are a lot of button, each click of a button get a node of the json and populate the HTML.

json:

```json
{
   textOne: "some phrase 1 ",
   textTwo: "some phrase 2 ",
   foo: "bar ",
   dot: " . ",
   questionMark: " ? ",
   anotherNode: "another text ",
}
```

and it creates a HTML like this:

```html
<span data-id="textOne">some phrase 1 </span> 
<span data-id="dot"> . </span>
<span data-id="anotherNode">another text </span> 
<span data-id="foo"> bar </span>
```

and the result is this: **some phrase 1 . another text  bar**

But i have to set like this:  **Some phrase 1. Another text bar.**

```html
<span data-id="textOne">Some phrase 1</span> 
<span data-id="dot">.</span>
<span data-id="anotherNode">Another text</span> 
<span data-id="foo">bar.</span>
```

- The first letter, must be capitalized,
- The period (dot, question mark, exclamation) must be just after the letter, without space,
- Any letter ater a period (dot, question mark, exclamation) must be capitalized
- the last word of the sentence must have a period (.)

My json file is way more complex than this, have about 10k lines. there is no way to manipule that. I have to manipule the HTML result.

Is there a way that i can input my HTML and get it formatted? without losing my HTML tags, i've seen some answers about it, but none with HTML tag in the sentence

the js to render manipule all json is really complex, a lot of rules.

But here is the part that creates the HTML:

```js
//there is a loop that call this function for each click, `this._tmpSentence` is the final sentence, with all HTML tags
 createSentenceForText({ element, reference }) {
    if (element && element.text) {
      const span = ` <span data-reference="${reference}.text" data-id="${element.id}">` // the space at the beginning ensure 2 words don't come together
      const text = this.handlerText(element.text)
      const cspan = `</span> `
      this._tmpSentence = this._tmpSentence + span + text + cspan
    }
  }

 // in the json, the phrases can come with [br] [i] or [b] that i have to swap to <br> <i> and <strong>
 handlerText(text) {
    if (!text) return
    text = text.replace(/\[b\]/g, '<strong>').replace(/\[\/b\]/g, '</strong>')
    text = text.replace(/\[i\]/g, '<i>').replace(/\[\/i\]/g, '</i>')
    text = text.replace(/\[br\]/g, '<br>')
    return text
  }
```

to see the staging version of the plataform, https://staging.leorad.com.br/laudador/50

click on **análise** on the top navigation, then, deselect anything of the side bar, then click on all buttons of the middle panel

Comment: Not really enough info, can you give us a better snippet of the json, and the existing js that renders this as html? Will dot always contain a ''." char, will questionMark always contain a "?" char, when do you want to render a '.' and when do you want to render a '?' i.e what logic displays a '.' in your snippet above and why was not not a "?"

Comment: @Spangle here's one json: https://legacy.leorad.com.br/legacy-api/templates/50
there are hundreds like this.
you have to parse `JSON.parse()`

there is no pattern with all text and periods, some ends with space, some not, but all node when rendered must have space between 2 texts. The JS that renders it I'm still working on it, this kind complexity i need to use tree traversal to iterate all node of the json. and the think we can forget about the json and focus on the HTML, how to output another peace of HTML from that.. ahh, and tkss

Comment: Please add your javascript function you are using to build your HTML, there are many ways to accomplish this

Comment: the js to do that is about thousands of lines, it's really complex, a lot of rules, but edited the question with a part of the code that renders the html

Answer (score 1):

Applying the transformations at the time of generating the HTML would be much easier. You can have a logic to transform the values based on the value of the last node as well as the current value.

For example,

1. If the `id` is `dot`, then remove the leading space.
2. If the last node was `dot`, then capitalize the first word of the current node.
   etc.

If you are not able to transform the values at the time of HTML generation, then you could parse the HTML and apply the same transformations.

Another alternative is to use CSS classes to make the HTML render the way you need without actually changing the node values in the HTML.

For example, the following HTML & CSS will capitalize the first letters of the first node and every nodes following a dot. It will also show a dot after the last node.

HTML:

```
<span data-id="textOne">some phrase 1 </span> 
<span data-id="dot" class="dot"> . </span>
<span data-id="anotherNode">another text </span> 
<span data-id="foo"> bar </span>
```

CSS:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}

span:first-child::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.dot + span::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

span:last-child::after {
  content: ".";
}
```

Comment: that's a good approach, i will store the last node then i will check how to manipule the next one. the `span:last-child::after` won't work, because some of my text has and some has not the period at the end, and this might end up with duplicated periods ..
also i cannot do it with CSS, unfortunately, because i have to send the HTML to another platforms (pacs and ris), i will only send the HTML, not the CSS

Answer (score 0):

A wonderful library for string parsing is [lodash](https://lodash.com/), but there are other ways of capitalizing the first letter found [here](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/capitalize)

I will give my example using lodash for simplicity

```js
const { capitalize } = require('lodash')

const parseRecord = record => {
  if (record.textOne) {
    // ensure first letter is capitalized of the sentence, and any word after a '.'
    const a = capitalize(record.textOne).split('.')
    let t = ''
    a.map(part => {
      t += capitalize(part)
    })
    record.textOne = t
  }
  
  if (record.dot) record.dot = ` ${String(record.dot).trim()} `
  
  // other parsing here ...
  return record
}

const builder = () = {
  // load your json into memory here
  const records = [{
    textOne: "some phrase 1 ",
    textTwo: "some phrase 2 ",
    foo: "bar ",
    dot: " . ",
    questionMark: " ? ",
    anotherNode: "another text "
  }]

  // iterate over each JSON object
  records.map(record => {
    const obj = parseRecord(record)
    // build your html here ...
  })
}

// run builder
builder()
```